# PHP Sending Duplicate Emails

Tags: php, email

After some more troubleshooting I believe I found the problem. We use QR Tags for our product and when a QR code is scanned it takes the user to the URL that runs this script. If I manually type in the URL or if I use our custom built QR scanner app then the user will receive one email. However if I user any other QR scanning app then it will send multiple emails. How can I make it so that this script will run only once each time the URL is loaded even if its from a third party app?

```
<?php 

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$count=-6; 
$id=substr($queryString,$count,6); 

//db connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost', '*****', '*****', '*****');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `****` where id = '$id'";
$result = $db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$email = $row['email'];
$ownername = $row['ownername'];
$petname = $row['petname'];

//check to see if tag has been registered
if ($email != "") {

    //send email
    $datetime = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
    $subject = "Alert";

    $mailheader.= "From: " . "Tag Team <support@tag.com>\n";
    $mailheader.= "X-Sender: " . "support@tag.com\n";
    $mailheader.= "Return-Path: " . "support@tag.com\n";
    $mailheader .= "Bcc: support@tag.com";

    $body .= "Dear " . $ownername . ", \n\n";

    $body .= "" . $petname . "'s Tag has just been scanned.\n\n";
    $body .= "Click here to Login :\n";
    $body .= "http://www.tag.com\n";
    $body .= "********************\n\n";
    $body .= "Regards,";
    $body .= " \n\n";
    $body .= "Tag Team";
    $body .= " \n\n";
    $body .= "Keeping Pets Safe and Found";

    mail($email, $subject, $body, $mailheader ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");

    //end email alert
}

header("Location: http://www.smartphonepettag.com/id/profile.php?id=$id");
mysql_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: Do you call this file from somewhere else?

Comment: How is this page being loaded? If it's with a GET request, it could be that the page is just being loaded multiple times. Try making that page only available via POST. Non-idempotent requests (requests with side-effects) should not happen via GET. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Comment: Our user goes to p7p.co/(6digitID#). This loads this script and then redirects

Comment: This code only sends one email.  Your issue stems from something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code snippet I cannot see any reason why your script should be executed more than once but relating to [your post yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767469/php-email-wont-send-to-custom-email-addresses) it seems as if something on your mail server is going terribly wrong.

But anyway if it's not an mail server fault the solution would be something like this:

```
// add this at the very first line
session_start();
// add this in the code
if($_SESSION['send'] != true){
  mail($email, $subject, $body, $mailheader ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
  $_SESSION['send'] = true;
}
```

This will make sure that the "mail()" function will never be executed twice for the same user.
You can learn more about Session Variables at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: I added this to my code and so far I am only receiving one email. Hopefully this will work. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a flag in your database indicating if the email has been sent. Check the flag before sending the email, set it after you send the email.